# Prevent collection from being modified while enumerating

Tags: c#, collections, enumeration

how do i prevent Collection from being modified during Enumeration.

Here is the class source code.

```
 public class cars : IEnumerator,IEnumerable
 {
  private car[] carlist;
  int position = -1;

  public IEnumerator GetEnumerator()
  { return (IEnumerator)this; }

  public bool MoveNext()
  {
     position++;
     return (position < carlist.Length);
  }

  public void Reset()
  {position = 0;}

  //IEnumerable
  public object Current
  { get { return carlist[position];}
  }
 }
```

Comment: @Downvoter: Why the downvote? Might be best to tell the OP what's wrong with the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At least some of the BCL collections do this by including a version counter. Each modification of the collection increments the counter. When an enumeration of the collection is started the current value of the version count is kept. On each call to the enumerator's `MoveNext` the underlying collection's version is checked against the kept counter, if different an exception is thrown.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, your collection class should not implement `IEnumerator` – it should implement `IEnumerable` only and return an instance of another class that implements `IEnumerator` (possibly `carEnumerator`) when `GetEnumerator()` is called.

`IEnumerator` (implemented in `carEnumerator`) extends `IDisposable` so, in `cars.GetEnumerator()`, you can set a private flag (perhaps `private bool isEnumerating`) to true. In `carEnumerator`, keep a reference to the collection (cars) and, in `carEnumerator.Dispose()`, set `isEnumerating` back to false.

Finally, in all the methods in cars that you want to disable while enumeration is ongoing, check the state of `isEnumerating` and throw an exception or do nothing if it is true.

Comment: Note: the non-generic version of IEnumerator does not, in fact, extend IDisposable. Either use the generic interfaces (IEnumerable<car>, IEnumerator<car>) or mark carEnumerator to extend both IEnumerator and IDisposable. After a for-each statement, Dispose() will be called if the enumerator is disposable.